# Cómo puedo hacer un "Reloj" en Javascript para principiantes, usando funciones, condicionales y ciclos

Tags: javascript

Buen día!

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y me encontré con un ejercicio interesante en `Javascript`, el cual consiste en crear un "reloj", en el que se busca, básicamente, que se imprima en la consola cada hora con cada uno de sus minutos y estos con cada uno de sus segundos, es decir, desde las 00:00:00 hasta las 23:59:59 pasando por cada segundo del día

La solución más eficiente que encontré fue usando 3 ciclos `for` sin más. Sin embargo, por deseo propio, estoy intentando hacer el ejercicio haciendo uso de funciones, condicionales y ciclos (primero con el `for`), de forma que ponga que práctica lo que he visto de esto.

La forma en que lo estoy abordando consiste en tener tres funciones; una de segundos, otra de minutos y otra de horas, en la cual en cada una aumentan estas respectivas variables hasta sus límites (60, 60 y 24) y, dadas ciertas condiciones, como que cuando los segundos marquen 60, aumente el contador de minuto a 1 y el de segundos otra vez sea 0, y así cada vez e igualmente con las horas.

Hasta el momento he logrado que cada función muestre precisamente su conteo desde, por ejemplo, las 0h 0m 0s hasta las 0h 1m 0s (para el caso de la función de los segundos, es decir, he logrado pasar e imprimir cada segundo de ese primer minuto). Pero no he logrado integrar las 3 funciones para tener el resultado deseado y explicado en el primer párrafo: imprimir cada hora con sus respectivos 60 minutos y estos con sus respectivos 60 segundos.

Explicado esto, quisiera saber si es posible hacer esto que quiero hacer o si no se puede. Y en caso de poderse, cómo podría hacerlo?

Por otro lado, de qué otra forma se puede abordar este ejercicio haciendo uso de funciones, condicionales y el ciclo `for`?

Agradezco cualquier corrección y consejo, disculpen todo el contexto!

Muchas gracias!

Adjunto el código que tengo de cada función en cuestión:

```js
//////RELOJ CON CONDICIONALES//////
//Defino variables iniciales
let hrs = 0;
let min = 0;
let seg = 0;
//Defino funciones
function seconds(seg, min) {
  for (let s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
    if (seg >= 59) {
      seg = 0;
      min += 1;
      console.log(min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    } else {
      seg += 1;
      console.log(min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    }
  }
}

function minutes(min, hrs) {
  for (let m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
    if (min >= 59) {
      min = 0;
      hrs += 1;
      console.log(hrs + "hrs" + min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    } else {
      min += 1;
      console.log(hrs + "hrs" + min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    }
  }
}

function hours(hrs) {
  for (let h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
    if (hrs >= 23) {
      hrs = 0;
      console.log(hrs + "hrs" + min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    } else {
      hrs += 1;
      console.log(hrs + "hrs" + min + "min" + seg + "seg");
    }
  }
}
seconds(seg, min)
minutes(min, hrs)
hours(hrs)
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Deberías llamar a minutos y segundos desde adentro de las otras funciones y no invocarlas por separado. Esto hace que primero se ejecute la función segundos y haga lo que este adentro y así sucesivamente.

Esta seria una forma de hacerlo usando esas funciones, solo que sin condicionales, pero podrías usar condicionales añadiéndole la característica de poder cambiar el formato de la hora entre 24 o 12.

Si te das cuenta yo llamo a minutos dentro de la función hora y a segundos dentro de la función minutos. Espero te sirva. Saludos!

```js
function seconds (string){
    for (let seg = 0; seg <= 59; seg++)
    {
        console.log(`${string} ${seg} seg`);
    }
}
function minutes (string)
{
    for (let min = 0; min <= 59; min++)
    {
        seconds(`${string }${min} min`);
    }   
}

function hours ()
{
    let string = "";
    for (let hour = 0; hour <= 23; hour++)
    {
        string = `${hour} hrs `
        minutes(string);
        string = "";
    }    
}

hours()
```